# Add a new column to dataframe after comparing the values of other columns

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have the dataframe below:

```
def<-c("BAL","DEN","DEN")
home<-c("DEN","DEN","BAL")
away<-c("BAL","BAL","DEN")

def home away
1 BAL  DEN  BAL
2 DEN  DEN  BAL
3 DEN  BAL  DEN
```

My goal is to create a new column named `def2` which will include the opposite team from the one that is included in the `def` column. In order to find the name of that team it should check the values of `home` and `away` columns. The final dataset should be like:

```
def home away def2
1 BAL  DEN  BAL  DEN
2 DEN  DEN  BAL  BAL
3 DEN  BAL  DEN  BAL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `df` is your dataframe, in base R you can use

```
df$def2 <- ifelse(df$def == df$home, df$away, df$home)
#   def home away def2
# 1 BAL  DEN  BAL  DEN
# 2 DEN  DEN  BAL  BAL
# 3 DEN  BAL  DEN  BAL
```

---

If you are in a `dplyr` pipeline, you can use

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(def2 = if_else(def == home, away, home))
```